# Disentangle the [yarn]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are at least 100+ questions that are using the [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn) tag when they should be using [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg), and the number isn't going down.

The package manager is only gaining in popularity and people apparently aren't reading tag wikis much as most [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg) questions seem to end up in [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn) first, which is bad for review queues and watchers of both tags alike.

It would be helpful if we could avoid the ambiguity in the first place, maybe by renaming [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn) to [yarn-hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-hadoop) or similar?

Comment: I'm totally not impartial and would be in favour of keeping yarn as the JavaScript package manager, but maybe a compromise of renaming both of them and preventing yarn's use could do the trick?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I'm having a hard time understanding your comment. This question is already suggesting exactly what you are suggesting, isn't it?

Comment: I've seen questions tagged as both [yarn] AND [yarnpkg] (the question was only about yarnpkg). I think the solution suggested here makes the most sense.

Comment: @leonheess hmm maybe I misunderstand, but I was under the impression that in the question here, the tag "yarn", without specifier, would still count as "yarn-hadoop". I propose that it be prevented from use instead, as suggested in your answer :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier The question proposes [yarn] to be effectively removed by renaming it. This would not prevent reinstatement at a later time which is why I suggested a blacklisting as well. AFAIK either way [yarn] would be removed.

Comment: Considering the confusion seems to persist to this day (~Q4 2020), this still seems like an excellent idea.

Comment: I feel for the original `yarn` tag usage though. Their term has been hijacked because another software used the name and became more widely known (apparently?), which definitely sucks to some extent.

Answer (score 16):

I think this is a no-brainer and should have been done in 2017 when it was proposed. Every day I come across posts tagged with [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn) when they are about [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg). I went through all [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn)-questions and retagged or closed them if they were about [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg). The community seems to be in favor as well - so what are we waiting for?

Let's rename [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn) to [yarn-hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-hadoop)! (Maybe even blacklist [yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn) afterwards.)