# Let's weave the [yarnpkg] tags together

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I'm the lead maintainer of [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), a JS package manager. I noticed questions about it are currently spread into many tags:

[yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg)[yarn-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-v2)[yarnpkg-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg-v2)[yarnpkg-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg-v3)[yarn-workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-workspaces)[yarn-lock.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-lock.json)

The Yarn 1 -> 2 transition came with an exceptional rewrite of the codebase so I can conceive that keeping two separate tags between "pre-2.0" and "post-2.0" may make sense, but adding more of them for each major or each feature is imo unnecessary.

Would it be possible to consolidate the existing [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg)[yarn-workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-workspaces)[yarn-lock.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-lock.json) into [yarnpkg-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg-classic) (which is the name we give to "pre-2.0"), and [yarn-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-v2)[yarnpkg-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg-v2)[yarnpkg-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg-v3) into [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg) (or [yarnpkg-berry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg-berry) if you prefer, which is "post-2.0")?

Comment: (I am not very familiar with yarn, but imho it is pretty okay) Some similar happened also to angular(js). Btw, if the change between 2 and 3 is really not so big, why did you bump the major version number?

Comment: Rather than merging, could they not be woven together?

Comment: What a tangled web has been woven.

Comment: @peterh between 2 and 3? because it contains a few breaking changes. Most of them aren't likely to affect our users or have significant impact (renaming settings, etc), but on the off chance we prefer to batch them in a single end-of-year release that we publish as formal major.

Comment: Why [yarnpkg] and not [yarn]?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas that's a separate issue, cf https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn

Comment: [yarn] is now [hadoop-yarn] per the other Meta (with synonym). Should help this out a bit

Answer (score 1):

I can see the need for this, but your tag suggestions doesn't work with existing nomenclature.

We have [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), which encompasses [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), which is the best example of a versioning epoch in SO tags. As such [yarnpkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg) should remain as a generic tag so users can find it. Instead, you use the version specific tags when it's version specific (trust me, people will still tag it however they see fit).

We probably need a [yarnpkg-1.x] tag (can synonym [yarnpkg-classic] as well). There are no v1 specific tags, however. The tag will have to be created and questions added first.

It looks like [yarn-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarn-v2) is really a synonym of [yarnpkg-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg-v2) (only one was related to Hadoop). I would also propose we rename [yarnpkg-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yarnpkg-v2) to [yarnpkg-2.x]. The other v2 tags can be synonymed as requested.

Comment: If there's an explicit 2.x tag, it feels like there should be a 3.x one as well for the rare cases where the two are different.  Either that or something like `yarnpkg-v2/3`?